How to identify the natural vector bundle structure on the endomorphism bundle of a smooth manifold?
How to identify the natural vector bundle structure on the endomorphism bundle of a smooth manifold?
Let $ M $ be a smooth $\mathbb{R} $-manifold. The endomorphism bundle is defined as:
$
\operatorname{End}_\mathbb{R}(TM) = \{ \Phi : TM \to TM \mid \forall p \in M, \Phi_p : T_pM \to T_pM \text{ is an } \mathbb{R}\text{-linear map, and } \pi \circ \Phi = \pi \}
$
Given this, what is the natural vector bundle structure on $ \operatorname{End}_\mathbb{R}(TM) $ such that the projection $ \pi : \operatorname{End}_\mathbb{R}(TM) \to M $ becomes a smooth map between manifolds? More generally, how can we systematically identify the natural vector bundle structure in situations like this?
Any insights or clarifications on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated!

You might enjoy Chapter 3 of Milnor's book Characteristic Classes, where he gives a completely general construction along these lines. I'll outline how it is applied, but for the proof I would suggest just reading it: it's really too elaborate to outline, but I would say that the proof is "just" an elaborate "follow your nose" argument, always doing the next obvious thing that needs to be done. But as always with Milnor, exactly the right things are said to make the proof crystal clear. I'll say a very few words foggy words about the proof below.
The construction starts with some very general kind of functor $F$ of vector spaces.
Then, for any manifold $M$, and for an vector bundle $\xi$ over $M$, the construction produces a natural vector bundle $F\xi$ over $M$ whose fibers are the vector spaces obtained by applying the functor $F$ to the bundle $\xi$ one fiber at a time, i.e. applying the functor to each vector space $\xi_p$ ($p \in M$) to produce the vector space $F \xi_p$.
For a very few words about the proof, one works first in each coordinate chart of $\xi$ over $U \subset M$ to produce the vector bundle $F (\xi \mid U)$ just by a product construction. One then applies to functor to the $\xi$-overlap map $(\xi \mid U)_p \mapsto (\xi \mid V)_p$ associated to any two charts $U,V$ and any point $p \in U \cap V$, in order to define the "gluing maps" $F(\xi \mid U)_p \mapsto F(\xi \mid V)_p$ which identifies the fiber over $p$ in one chart with the fiber over $p$ in the other chart. One then must use the overlap conditions for $\xi$ and functoriality properties of $F$ to prove the overlap conditions for $F\xi$.
In your case one would apply this construction using the functor which assigns to each $V$ its endomorphisms $\text{End}_{\mathbb R} V$, and using the vector bundle $\xi=TM$.
The construction even works for functors whose input is a tuple of vector spaces, and Milnor describes some useful examples in that situation.

Great and detailed answer,exactly what I was looking for.Thank you!

Well,I just figured out another way to get the vector bundle structure on $End(TM)$ which is by the natural identification $End(TM)=T^M\otimes TM$ and then we can look at this endomorphism bundle of $TM$ as a tensor bundle.The identification I have given here between the endomorphism bundle and the tensor bundle occurred from a natural isomorphism between $V^\otimes W\simeq Hom(V,W)$ for $V,W$ finite dimensional vector spaces.,the identification is given by $\varphi\otimes w\mapsto T_{\varphi,w}$ where $T_{\varphi,w}(v)=\varphi(v)w$.

You still need Milnor's construction for your solution, using the tensor product functor from pairs of vector spaces to single vector spaces.
